# role field not stored in database after identitymanager role creation

Tags: java, security, seam

I'm using seam 2.1.2 security and I create a role using identitymanager by jsf richfaces GUI. in creation process I would add a "description" to role created in database , the creation of role is ok but the description field is not added, I must update the role (in other operation by GUI) to see the description field stored in database. the question is what have I to do to store the "description" filed in creation operation?

bellow is my code:

```
  public boolean createRole(Role role) {
    IdentityManager identityManager = IdentityManager.instance();
logger.info("creating role:" + role.getRoleName());
if (identityManager.roleExists(role.getRoleName())) {
    return false;
}
if (identityManager.createRole(role.getRoleName())) {
    completeRolePersistence(role);
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

and the completeRolePersistence method:

```
public void completeRolePersistence(Role role) {
    logger.info("setting additional info to role...");
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("UPDT_ADDITIONALS");
    query.setParameter("name", role.getRoleName())
            .setParameter("description", role.getDescription())
            .setParameter("level", role.getRoleLevel());
    int updated = query.executeUpdate();
    logger.info("roles updated with desc : " + updated);
}
```

it seem that the query is not executed , i print in log

```
roles updated with desc : 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because your update query is executing **BEFORE** the role is actually inserted into the database, thus it updates nothing.

My advice is to not use the role/user creation methods in `IdentityManager`. You're better off creating Home components to create/edit your roles and users than having `IdentityManager` do it for you.

If you however want to pursue this, you need to overwrite `JpaIdentityStore`, customize the `createRole` method and have it populate the entity as needed.

Comment: That works perfect thx , i use juste persist method from entitymanager and it store role with all fileds and permissions in db